# Removing automaticly injected CSS styles in Angular 2/ Ionic 2

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript, ionic2

The problem I am having is that when I add the ionic 2 [gesture](https://ionicframework.com/docs/components/#gestures) (press) on a button it keeps automatically adding inline styles to that button.

Is there a way to overrule the style it adds?

**Button**

```
<button ion-button (press)="toggleFavourite(sound)" (click)="share(sound.file)"></button>
```

**CSS it adds because of the (press) gesture.**

```
style="
touch-action: none; 
user-select: none; 
-webkit-user-drag: none; 
-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);"
```

Comment: You can overrule with your own css by adding `!important` after each property

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just do it as shown below on your `page.scss` file.

**Note:** Don't use `!import` hack.Which is very BAD.

**page.scss**

```
.ios,
.md,
.wp {
    page-my {
        .my-gesture {
           touch-action: none; 
           user-select: none; 
          -webkit-user-drag: none; 
          -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
        }
}
```

**page.html**

```
 <button ion-button class="my-gesture" (press)="toggleFavourite(sound)" 
 (click)="share(sound.file)"></button>
```